# Is it possible to combine pack layout (circles) with partition layout (sunburst) using d3.js library?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, circle-pack, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to group circles, that are visualized trough pack layout (Bubble Chart) from json file, in partitions that are made with Sunburst Partition layout. So far I could not make it work in various attempts. But if it is not possible, what is the most similar way or any way to group circles visualized by pack layout?

I tried to group them also with force layout, but when I use function for collision the circles are jumping something like 30 seconds. Any suggestions, thank you :)

This is also something that I want: (altough it is not sunburst partition)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Combining the sunburst and circle packing layout doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to achieve? You can use the pack layout by itself to group circles, see e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530).

Comment: Lars, here is what I want to achive [link](http://i44.tinypic.com/1z724d3.jpg). Only to put these circles in one of 8 partitions depending on ID of circle. Any idea? Thanks for your answer, I will try to group them like you said, hope wont have any problems.

Comment: Could you use the circle packing layout for each partition separately?

Comment: No, I can't. I put the "g" element where is circle located, into path element that is partition, but nothing happend. When I use inspect element option from Chrome broswer I can see that circles are inside the path but they are not shown.

Comment: Lars, this pack layout that group circles is based on parent-child process, is it possible to group them by IDs, becouse in my json file there is array with more than 1000 objects and all have the same level?

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Surely the IDs are different for all of them and grouping by that wouldn't make much sense?

Comment: Sorry I sad ID, I ment to Group them by their category_id. In my json file I have array of objects, and all of objects have that "category_id". There are 8 different category_ids. So I just want to group circles (that objects from json) that have the same category_id in one big circle or group. I hope now I sad what I thought :) Sorry again, and thanks man :)

Comment: You would need to convert your data structure with IDs into something hierarchical that you can use with D3's layouts.

Comment: Thanks man, I thought of that. I will try to do like you said.